# Map to KML tool issue: legend is cut off in Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth, legend

I am facing this issue with MAP to KML tool in ArcGIS Desktop (10.2.2): I have created the legend in Map Layout as indicated [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s200000009000000) then exported to KML. But the legend is partially cut off in Google Earth. I have already tried increasing spacing and halo, but it does not solve the problem. 
Does anyone have experienced the same issue and/or can suggest solutions?

[image]

Comment: Did you try converting the legend to a graphic and then exporting?

Comment: Hi, I didn't try because I remember reading in some GIS forum (I can't track it back) one should NOT convert to graphic. However, I did try after reading your post, but my unknown source was right: if legend is converted to graphic it is not exported as overlay by MAP to KML tool